# Reduction of the $S_3$ group representation

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Let $e_1$ and $\psi$ be two polynomials, and consider the subspace $V$ of $\mathbb{C}[t,u,v]$ spanned by $e_1(x)\psi(y)$ where $x,y\in \{t,u,v\}$. Then $V$ carries a representation of the symmetric group $S_3$ by permutation on the three variables $\{t,u,v\}$, and we want to reduce the representation $V$. The group $S_3$ has 3 irreducible representations (trivial, alternating and standard) with respective dimensions $1$, $1$ and $2$.

I did the following:

Reduction is made according to the group chain: $S_3 \supseteq S_2$ and intrinsic group of $S_2$. For $S_3 \supseteq S_2$ I defined class operator $D(S_3)=D(tu)+D(tv)+D(uv)$ and $D(S_2)=D(tu)$. And for intrinsic group of $S_2$ $D(s_2)=D(12)$. $D(*)$ represent matrix representation and, for example, $(tu)$ represent permutation where $v$ is unchainged and $t$ is permutated to $u$ and vise versa. Set of operators $(D(S_3),D(S_2),D(s_2)$ is complite set of commutating operators.

From this we get eigen equations:
$$D(S_3) \psi_{(\lambda, m, k)}=\lambda \psi_{(\lambda, m, k)}$$
$$D(S_2) \psi_{(\lambda, m, k)}=m \psi_{(\lambda, m, k)}$$
$$D(s_2) \psi_{(\lambda, m, k)}=k \psi_{(\lambda, m, k)}$$
Eigenvalues:
$$\lambda=\{-3,0,3\}$$
$$m=\{1,-1\}$$
$$k=\{1,-1\}$$
When eigenvector equations are solved, I get following 9 vectors:
$$\psi_{(3,1,1)}^{a}=e_1(t) \psi_1 + e_1(u) \psi_2+e_1(v)\psi_3$$
$$\psi_{(3,1,1)}^{b}=e_1(v) \psi_1 + e_1(t) \psi_2+e_1(u)\psi_3+e_1(u) \psi_1 + e_1(v) \psi_2+e_1(t)\psi_3$$
$$\psi_{(3,-1,-1)}=e_1(v) \psi_1 + e_1(t) \psi_2+e_1(u)\psi_3-e_1(u) \psi_1 - e_1(v) \psi_2-e_1(t)\psi_3$$
$$\psi_{(0,-1,k)}=e_1(t) \psi_1 - e_1(u) \psi_2$$
$$\psi_{(0,1,k)}=e_1(t) \psi_1 + e_1(u) \psi_2-2e_1(v)\psi_3$$
$$\psi_{(0,-1,1)}=e_1(v) \psi_1 -e_1(u)\psi_3- e_1(v) \psi_2+e_1(t)\psi_3$$
$$\psi_{(0,1,1)}=e_1(v) \psi_1 -2 e_1(t) \psi_2+e_1(u)\psi_3-2e_1(u) \psi_1 + e_1(v) \psi_2+e_1(t)\psi_3$$
$$\psi_{(0,1,-1)}=-e_1(v) \psi_1 +e_1(u)\psi_3 - e_1(v) \psi_2+e_1(t)\psi_3$$
$$\psi_{(0,-1,-1)} =-e_1(v) \psi_1 +2 e_1(t) \psi_2-e_1(u)\psi_3-2e_1(u) \psi_1 + e_1(v) \psi_2+e_1(t)\psi_3$$

$\psi_{(3,1,1)}^{a}$ and $\psi_{(3,1,1)}^{b}$ form trivial representation of $S_3$ while  $\psi_{(3,-1,-1)}$ form alterneiting representation. Remaining 6 vectors span 3 standard two dimensional representations.

After that, I defined similarity transformation matrix $T$ and got $(tuv)$ permutation matrix in new basis:
\begin{equation}
  (tuv)_{2}= T_1(tuv)_1 {T_1}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -3/2 & -1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1/2 & -1/2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3/2 & -1/2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1/2 & -1/2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3/2 & -1/2\\
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Finding $(tu)$ matrix is analogous and since this 2 permutations span whole group $S_3$ other matrices can be obitained trivially with multiplications of this 2 matrices.

Questions are following: I belive this is correct solution but I have trouble finding good literature. Where can I read more about this? Most books I found about representation theory of groups are too difficult to understend for me. Are all 3 standard representations which were obitened equivalent? Can they be named differently?

On https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Standard_representation_of_symmetric_group:S3 I found following matrix element for standard representation:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
-1/2 & -\sqrt{3}/2\\
 \sqrt{3}/2 & -1/2\\
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
for $(123)$ permutation and my matrix element looks like this:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
-1/2 & -1/2\\
 3/2 & -1/2\\
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
I did not write all other matrices here but when I check traces of matrices (characters) they are all as they should be. What rises a confusion is this $\sqrt{3}$. Did I make mistake in my calculation? I have a lot of question about this so best solution for me is to get a good book which can help me. I am hoping someone will recognize at least something and give me good direction on where to search for solution. I never had any classes about reduction of groups at my university so a lot of this is completly new for me. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you give more context? You seem to use a multiplication on vectors, what is that about?

Comment: I asume you are asking about $e_1(i)\psi(i)$ for $i=t,u,v$. $e_1(i)$ and $\psi(i)$ are both polynomial therefore  $e_1(i)\psi(i)$ is  polynomial. Example: using permutation $(tu)$ on $e_1(t)\psi(t)$ gives $e_1(u)\psi(u)$

Comment: Ok, I modified the beginning so that it would be easier to understand.

Comment: Two comments: A) For some choices of $e_1$ and $\psi$ the space $V$ won't be 9-dimensional. Consider for example $e_1(x)=x=\psi(x)$. B) I don't understand what the role of the subgroup $S_2$ is here? Why don't you calculate the character and the usual inner products?

Comment: Oh, and C) the matrices $$\pmatrix{-1/2&-\sqrt3/2\cr \sqrt3/2&-1/2\cr}$$ and
$$\pmatrix{-1/2&-1/2\cr 3/2&-1/2\cr}$$ are similar. In other words they may represent the same linear transformation w.r.t. different bases. Conjugate one by the diagonal matrix with entrier $1,\sqrt3$ to see this.